# Getting a PolicySyncError exception when creating a PolicyEngine

Tags: azure-information-protection, microsoft-information-protection

I am trying to run the [MipSdk-PolicyApi-Cpp-Sample-Basic](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/mipsdk-policyapi-cpp-sample-basic) sample. I have followed the exact instructions, but keep running into a `PolicySyncError` exception when creating the `PolicyEngine`:

> Failed acquiring policy, Request failed with http status code: 204

The same thing happens when running the pre-compiled File API sample with user credentials:

```
.\file_sample.exe -l --username xx@xx.onmicrosoft.com --password xx --clientid 591d68e3-4cf9-4138-8fa5-0304f72d729c
```

I have an E5 trial with policies and labels all set up correctly, as far as I can tell. I'd love to get any pointers, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Typically that indicates that the policy hasn't been published via [Security and Compliance Center](https://protection.office.com) (SCC).

If you haven't already done so, you'll need to migrate your label store to the unified store by following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/information-protection/configure-policy-migrate-labels), then publish a label policy in SCC. In SCC, find Classifications, then Label Policies. Create a new policy that includes the labels you've created.